# Sum of the diagonal elements in a Spiral Matrix in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have been given an array = [ 1 2 3 8 9 4 7 6 5 ] which is a spiral traversal of a square matrix of size n x n. What I needed to do was to compute the sum of primary and secondary diagonals and print it. I was able to convert this 1D array into a 2D array of size n*n and compute the sum of both diagonals like this:

**p.s.: array is something like this [ [1, 2, 3], [6, 5, 8], [7, 4, 9] ]**

```js
function spDiag(n,arr){
    let mat = [];
    let primary = 0, secondary = 0;
    while(arr.length) mat.push(arr.splice(0, n));
    
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if(i === j) primary += mat[i][j];
            
            if((i + j) === (n-1)) secondary += mat[i][j];
        }
        
    }
    console.log(primary + secondary)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(mat));
    
}

spDiag(3, [1,2,3,8,9,4,7,6,5])
```

But the task was to form a spiral matrix and then compute the sum of diagonals and not just a 2D matrix and because of this my output is coming wrong. How can I convert this 1D array to a spiral matrix?

Comment: You don't need the matrix to calculate the sum. The sum is `arr[0] + arr[2] + arr[4] + arr[6] + 2 * arr[8]`. That is `arr[0 * (n - 1)] + arr[1 * (n - 1)] + arr[2 * (n - 1)] + arr[3 * (n - 1)] + 2 * arr[arr.length - 1]`.

Comment: @jabaa Is it a generalized formula? I don't think so because for a spiral matrix of size 4 x 4 it doesn't hold up. Consider this array: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 16, 15, 14, 13, 9, 5, 6, 7, 11, 10 ]

Comment: First you add 4 times `n-1`. Then you add 4 times `n-2`. Then ... Yes, you can simply generalize it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more? I didn't get it

Comment: Take a piece of paper and create a square of size 3x3, spiral traverse it and count steps. You'll go 4 times 2 steps and once 1 step. Try it with a square of size 4x4. You'll go 4 times 3 steps, then 4 times 2 steps and once 1 step. Create a square with size 5x5. You'll go 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 steps. That's a general pattern. That's a mathematical puzzle. You should do some puzzling first.

Comment: Maybe there is a bug in my algorithm, but you should be able to fix.

Comment: Yep there sure is a bug. I'll try to understand it. Also, if you could suggest where can I solve such puzzles or anything similar like this?

Comment: https://adventofcode.com/ has similar puzzles. In one puzzle, you also have to traverse a matrix in a spiral pattern, but it's much more complex. As far as I remember, you have to traverse a 2D array instead of a 1D array already containing the spiral path. But it's possible that I'm confusing something and that puzzle was somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to turn the 1D array into a 2D array, nor do you need to visit *each* value in the array. The diagonals follow an easy pattern, as the index-distance between 2 consecutive elements on a diagonal follows a pattern.

See for instance for a matrix of 7x7 which indexes of the spiral sequence are on a diagonal:

```
 0  .  .  .  .  .  6
 . 24  .  .  . 28  .
 .  . 40  . 42  .  .
 .  .  . 48  .  .  .
 .  . 46  . 44  .  .
 . 36  .  .  . 32  .
18  .  .  .  .  . 12
```

The gaps between two consecutive indices that are on the diagonal (in order of index) are: 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2. The general pattern for these gaps is: −1,−1,−1,−1,−3,−3,−3,−3,...etc.

### Implementation

As the size of the given array is the square of , I don't see why you would need to pass  as argument. It is redundant information.

So:

```js
function sumDiagonals(arr) {
    let n = Math.sqrt(arr.length);
    if (n % 1) throw "Array size should be perfect square";
    let sum = 0;
    let len = n*2 - n%2; // The number of values on diagonals
    for (let i = 0, j = 0; j < len; i += n - 1 - (j++ >> 2)*2) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

let arr =  [1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 4, 7, 6, 5];
console.log(sumDiagonals(arr));
```

Comment: See, what will be the answer for the example array which I gave? It will be 30 right? And the code which you have written as per your logic is giving the output as 25.

Comment: If you say it is 30, it means the center element is counted twice. Is that what you want? I understood that a value should only be counted once (when it is on the diagonals). It  is probably a different interpretation. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry I was just checking the test cases and my bad actually both the answers can be accepted so it's not a problem. And I get it if we don't count the middle element twice then 25 is the answer. Cool. One more thing I am not getting clearly is... The gaps between two consecutive indices that are on the diagonal (in order of index) are: 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2. The general pattern for these gaps is: −1,−1,−1,−1,−3,−3,−3,−3,...etc.

Comment: The first index in the spiral sequence of a 7x7 matrix that has a number that is on a diagonal is 0 (top-left of matrix). The next index in the spiral sequence that has a number that is on a diagonal is 6 (top-right of matrix). So from 0 to 6 is a distance (gap) of 6, which is n-1 (n is 7 here). The next index in the spiral that has a number that is on a diagonal is 12 (bottom-right of matrix), so again the same gap, ...etc.

Comment: Ohh! Now got it. One last thing, I have searched for this question a lot although I have not found any solutions but every discussion I found involves looping through like taking four variables top, down, bottom, and left and taking four for loops, etc, etc. But this approach is unique. Did you find it out by yourself or have you read it from somewhere if you could tell me?

Comment: I just analysed it myself, and this is what I came up with. I understand that there are many ways to approach this. If I would look at this again two years from now, having forgotten about this question, I might come up with yet another approach. No-one really understands how our brains come up with ideas ;-)